# How to extract the path of an xml element in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I got this answer to a question i asked yesterday about how to use a path to access an element-

Is it possible to do the opposite?  means if i locate a specifiec element(level4 in the xml) with 
GetElementsByTagName method is there a way to get the path for this elements and assign it
to a variable for later use?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<level1> 
    <level2> 
        <level3>header3</level3> 
            <level4>header4</level4> 
        <level3>header31</level3> 
    </level2> 
    <level2> 
        <level3>nnn</level3> 
        <level3>nnnnn</level3> 
    </level2> 
</level1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have extracted your node by

> `XmlNodeList nl = doc.GetElementsByTagName("level4");`

then

```
        XmlNode node = nl[0]; 
        String sPath = node.Name;
        System.Xml.XmlNode np = node.ParentNode;
        while (np != null && np.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Document)
        {
            sPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}", np.Name, sPath);
            np = np.ParentNode;
        }
        sPath = "/" + sPath;
        Debug.WriteLine(sPath);
```

and you get "/level1/level2/level4" as the value of sPath

> *Note: this in correct because in the input XML **level3** is Sibling of **level4** ( not Parent )

Answer (score 1):

use XmlDocument object which can be found in System.Xml then use the ParentNode property until you get null ParentNode. Use recursive function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The XmlElement object already has a pointer to the parent object, so by following from parent to grandparent a.s.o. until you reach the document, you get the hierarchy in reverse.